# Is there evidence that means the sitting height is above 750?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to solve the following problem?

When designing a cinema, engineers consider the sitting eye height of the audience. a random sample of the eye sitting height of 20 men has been recorded. the summary statistics are the sample mean 787.95 and sample variance 30.35. Is there evidence that means the sitting height is above 750?

Thanks so much.

Comment: By "the sitting height" do you mean the mean sitting height of the population of men?  Presumably many in the audience will be women and children.  Are you just disregarding them?

Comment: Are you able to assume that sitting eye height is normally distributed? Your sample size of $n=20$ is a bit small. If so you want to perform the right tailed hypothesis test $H_0: \mu=750$ verses $H_a:\mu >750$. Since you don't know the population standard deviation your test statistic will be a $t$ score.

Comment: Since your histogram is bell shaped you're in the clear to assume normality.

Comment: @MatthewPilling:  not every "bell-shaped" distribution is normal, but I agree that one is supposed to assume that.

Comment: @Ross, yes you are right. I'm well aware of the numerous other bell shaped distributions. I'm just assuming Miss Q is learning statistics at an entry level; justifying the normal condition at this level is usually done by drawing a histogram and noting its shape. Usually if the histogram is absent of any "abnormal" properties like skewness, outliers, or multimodal features, then assuming a normal population is OK.